# Python WeakRef.WeakMethod pass arguments

Tags: python, weak-references, command-pattern

Currently I'm trying to create a class using the [Command Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command/).
For the action class, I have something similar to this:

```
class SimpleCommand(Command):
    """
    Some commands can implement simple operations on their own.
    """
    def __init__(self, callable: Callable) -> None:
        self._callable = callable

    def execute(self) -> None:
        self._callable()
```

To prevent memory leaks, I plan to maintain a weak reference to the callable method. Is there any way I can use weakref.WeakMethod and pass multiple arguments? I've attempted to use functools.partial, but this causes the the weak method to be perceived as dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding some additional arguments to the SimpleCommand class to allow arguments to be passed to the WeakMethod.

```
class SimpleCommand(Command):
"""
Some commands can implement simple operations on their own.
"""
def __init__(self, callable: Callable, *callable_args, **callable_kwargs) -> None:
    self._callable = weakref.WeakMethod(callable)
    self._callable_args = callable_args
    self._callable_kwargs = callable_kwargs

def execute(self) -> None:
    if self._callable() is not None:
        self._callable()(*self._callable_args, **self._callable_kwargs)
```